# How to recover deleted call logs from Android programmatically

Tags: android

Is there any way to recover deleted call history from Android mobile programmatically? Google search shows several applications like dr.fone for this purpose. But I could not find any example codes for the same.I have used the following code to get call logs from android but it includes only existing call logs.

```
private void getCallDetails() throws Exception{

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append( "Call Details :");
    while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
        String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
        switch( dircode ) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    call.setText(sb);
}
```